# Difficulty in verifying valide calls with boost::hana::is_valid

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae, boost-hana

I have a class `Foo` that can be constructed from C-style strings, string views and non-temporary strings (in reality it contains other members and methods, and it is templated on the character to pass to `basic_string*`s templates):

```cpp
struct Foo {
    explicit constexpr Foo()
        : text{}
    {}
    explicit constexpr Foo(std::string_view text)
        : text{std::move(text)}
    {}
    explicit constexpr Foo(char const* text)
        : Foo{std::string_view{text}}
    {}
    explicit constexpr Foo(char* text)
        : Foo{std::string_view{text}}
    {}
    explicit constexpr Foo(std::string&&) = delete;

    std::string_view text;
};
```

With the help of Boost.Hana, I can assert what `Foo` can be constructed from and what not, for documentation purposes, in a test:

```cpp
for_each(make_basic_tuple(
            type_c<std::string>,
            // clearly I'm not also listing type_c<int> and all the countless imaginable types that wouldn't work
            type_c<std::string&&>
            ),
        [](auto t){
            static_assert(!std::is_constructible_v<Foo, typename decltype(t)::type>);
        });
                                                                                      
for_each(make_basic_tuple(
            type_c<char*>,
            type_c<char const*>,
            // ...
            type_c<std::string_view>,
            type_c<std::string const&>
            ),
        [](auto t){
            static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<Foo, typename decltype(t)::type>);
        });
```

But via Boost.Hana, a `make_line` helper function is defined too:

```cpp
namespace boost::hana {
template <>
struct make_impl<Foo> {
    static constexpr Foo apply(const char* text) {
        return Foo{text};
    }
    static constexpr Foo apply(std::string const& text) {
        return Foo{text};
    }
    static constexpr Foo apply(std::string_view text) {
        return Foo{std::move(text)};
    }
    static constexpr Foo apply(std::string&&) = delete;
};
}

inline constexpr auto make_foo = boost::hana::make<Foo>;
```

and I can easily verify that it works only with the intendend category values of the arguments:

```cpp
make_foo("");
make_foo(""sv);
make_foo(sv);
make_foo(s);
//make_foo(std::move(s)); // correctly doesn't compile
//make_foo(""s);          // correctly doesn't compile
```

However, I'm not able to write this in a test via `hana::is_valid`. Here's my failed attampt:

```cpp
std::string s{};
std::string_view sv{};
                                                                                        
constexpr auto can_make_foo_from =
    is_valid([](auto&& obj) -> decltype(make_foo(std::forward<decltype(obj)>(obj))){});
                                                                                        
static_assert( decltype(can_make_foo_from(""))::value);
static_assert( decltype(can_make_foo_from(""sv))::value);
static_assert( decltype(can_make_foo_from(sv))::value);
static_assert( decltype(can_make_foo_from(s))::value);
//static_assert(!decltype(can_make_foo_from(std::move(s)))::value);
//static_assert(!decltype(can_make_foo_from(""s))::value);
```

where in my intentions the last 2 lines should compile, but they don't.

[Here's the full example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/aaa5q8Y6o).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [boost/hana/fwd/core/make.hpp](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/fwd/core/make.hpp) we can see:

```
template <typename Tag>
struct make_t {
    template <typename ...X>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(X&& ...x) const {
        return make_impl<Tag>::apply(static_cast<X&&>(x)...);
    }
};

template <typename Tag>
BOOST_HANA_INLINE_VARIABLE constexpr make_t<Tag> make{};
```

`decltype(auto)` doesn't trigger SFINAE.

So any `make<MyType>(Ts...)` is valid, but can generate hard errors.

Fix would be:

```
template <typename Tag>
struct make_t {
    template <typename ...X>
    constexpr auto operator()(X&& ...x) const
    -> decltype(make_impl<Tag>::apply(static_cast<X&&>(x)...))
    {
        return make_impl<Tag>::apply(static_cast<X&&>(x)...);
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MeE65a1W7)

Comment: Sad. :( I also had the tools to understand that. I mean, I knew that `decltype(auto)` is not sfinae friendly as `-> decltype(expr)` since I read it from [EMC++'s errata](https://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/emc++-errata.html). But thanks!